# Proper to use stored procedure to dynamically create charts?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, stored-procedures

I am working in rails and would like to add dynamic charts to my app. My thinking was that, given the data is in flat files, a stored procedure could be created in the MySQL db to query the data based on the parameters a user wishes to see, ie. sum users and group by activity they do (y-axis) by the months of the year (x-axis). The stored procedure would then be called from rails and return the result to be built into a chart.

However, it has bee noted that stored procedures are slow and therefore may kill the user experience if there are long loading times to simply render a chart.

For what I am trying to do is this the best way to proceed forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> stored procedures are slow

It has to be noted that stored procedures approach does not spend time on traversing data back and forth from your SQL server to `rails` and vice versa, so actually stored procedures should be executed much faster than traditional bunch of `ActiveRecord` queries.

> may kill the user experience if there are long loading times

Based on what the loading times and user queries could be, there is a variety of approaches to improve user experience:

1. You could render a page with some placeholding text like "Generating data, plase hold on for a while" and make results of analytical query appear a bit later using technique like AJAX or server-side events. Report generation could be processed in a background using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/). It's also possible to show something like a progress bar to let user know that his request is not abandoned.
2. You could take an advantage of caching data for common queries, so that each query is performed just once in a while. It's possible to choose different caching periods (e.g. update cached statistics once an hour or once a day) based on how relevant your chart should be. Take a look at [rails caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) manual page.
3. You could also be intested in some data mining researches, e.g. multi-dimensional  [online analytical processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) approach. The way of using OLAP cubes to represent data would be slightly more difficult to follow, but could improve your user experience with multidimensional data analysis possibilities.